# Многострочный комментарий Jinja2

Tags: jinja2

Мне нужно закомментировать большой кусок HTML кода в шаблоне с помощью Jinja. Я пытаюсь сделать это таким образом:

```
{#
html код тут
...
...
#}
```

Так написано в различных гайдах. Но у меня это не работает... В шаблон просто добавляются символы решетки и скобок...

Comment: У вас точно Jinja2?

Comment: @andreymal У меня джанговский язык, но ведь там синтаксис комментариев такой же как в jinja? Или фишка с многострочными там не работает? :(

Comment: Совсем не такой же, в Django для этого используется `{% comment %}` и `{% endcomment %}`

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое!

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса, т.к. проблема вызвана тем, что автор ошибочно считал, что у него в шаблонах использовался синтаксис jinja

Answer (score -1):

Многострочный комментарий в jinja пишется внутри тегов

```
{% comment %}

{% endcomment %}
```

Comment: В jinja не существует тега `{% comment %}`

Comment: Пожалуйста, проверяйте свои утверждения, прежде чем ставить минус.
Даже плагин django для vs code на горячие клавиши комментирования вставляет этот синтаксис. Лично я использовал это в версии 1.6

Comment: Django версии 1.6 не поддерживает jinja вообще. В более новых версиях поддержка jinja есть, но по умолчанию не используется и включать надо вручную. Проверяйте свои ответы и комментарии, прежде чем писать их